# Error invoking servlet, but other resources get loaded - Flex + Java Application

Tags: java, servlets, flex3, weblogic

I have written a RIA using flex for the front-end and Java servlet for the back end which actually makes calls to a web-service to do some processing.

The welcome page is a html page which is served from the web-logic 8.1 server that the app is hosted on. The welcome page loads and the flash content loads. Even a 'xml' file containing some configuration properties gets loaded from the server (through URL Request).

Now when I click a button on the page, it would authenticate the user, by sending the data to the servlet.

Here's the problem... The servlet doesn't get invoked and the URL Request (for the servlet with appropriate parameters) returns a 500: Internal Server Error page.

The same code is working perfectly when I deploy it on my local machine using tomcat as a server. And I have also checked umpteen times if the host URL is correct when being deployed on the web-logic server. Even checked the URL when the request is being made, in firefox, using firebug, and all seems to be fine, except that the response is '500: Internal Server Error'.

Please help. Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the welcome page loads, and an XML file loads from the webserver, but the servlet can't be invoked.

Is the servlet initialising correctly, and waiting to be called?

Does anything need to be changed in the web.xml file that hasn't been?

Comment: Essentially, both of these answers are correct. However I could tick only one :)

Turns out, it was a java version related error, which was discovered when checking the server logs. The code got build with jdk 1.6 while the web server could only handle java 1.4. Hence the servlet wasn't actually getting initialized. Since the page is a static resource, it was getting loaded fine but throwing errors only when the servlet was being invoked. Thanks again @Jaydee and @fizban for your inputs.

Answer (score 0):

Without any more information, it sounds like a misconfigured servlet and/or app server. Check your logs to see if there's any more information there.